# Difficulty executing command when raspberry pi loads

Tags: touchscreen

I have a raspberry pi 4B attached to a 7" raspberry pi touchscreen via the provided ribbon cable. In my application, I have my touchscreen rotated 90° by using `display_rotate` which is working correctly. The touchscreen input device needs to be separately rotated into the new coordinate system. I can do that locally by running the following `xinput` command:

```
    xinput set-prop 'raspberrypi-ts' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1
```

I want to run this command when the raspberry pi loads every time automatically, so I've edited my autostart file located in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@chromium-browser localhost
@xinput set-prop 'raspberrypi-ts' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1

@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

I'm able to run chromium automatically and load it to the requested page every time I restart the pi, but the touchscreen input is never rotated into the new coordinate system. If I enter the command into the terminal everything works like it should, but I really want it to happen automatically on boot.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there an issue with my formatting? Or is there a different location I should be adding this command so that it will be executed on load at the right time?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: what happens if you remove the chromium-browser line?

Comment: It still doesn’t execute the xinput command

Comment: introduce an error into the xinput command line to see if it returns an error message